# Bad request only on safari browser

Tags: php, ssl, safari, request

I have a problem that I do not understand, on this site, in https and safari I have a bad request, on other browsers it's ok

https://harguindeya-g241016-64250.gite-de-france-hh-p.locaguide-tourisme.com/fr

I did another test with a shorter url and it's ok on safari too

what is the limit of number of characters in an url? is it different in https than in http? I need the url recipe as I put it above

Thanks in advance for all the help

Comment: Might be a security feature of Safari - you're trying to go to the page via HTTPS, but you don't seem to have a (valid) SSL installed.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your certificate is only for *.locaguide-tourisme.com. If you would try it for https://locaguide-tourisme.com/ or https://gite-de-france-hh-p.locaguide-tourisme.com/ it have to work.

Works:

*.locaguide-tourisme.com
locaguide-tourisme.com

Don't work:

*.*.locaguide-tourisme.com

You could only use one dot or two dots with the .com.

Comment: thank you for  your response, but, this url :

https://munhoa-g131146-64220.gite-de-france-hautes-pyrenees.locaguide-tourisme.com/fr

it work in chrome and not work on safari